# Run Code Snippet focuses on textarea after "copy to answer"

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When you use the "Copy snippet to answer" functionality on a code snippet and click the "Run code snippet" while still in edit mode, the answer textarea gets focus and the page is scrolled  up to it instead of showing your result.

This is quite annoying when you want to keep testing your results while modifying your answer, and it seems like a bug to me.

Reproduce:

1. Go to a [question with a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915905/how-to-properly-position-tooltips-over-an-absolute-positioned-element/25960843#25960843)
2. Click "Copy snippet to answer"
3. Click "Run code snippet" in your answer preview

You are now seeing your editor, not your snippet result

Comment: Recently noticed and reported on [Code Review's Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/remove-scroll-back-to-answer-textarea-on-clicking-run-code-snippet-when-creati).

Comment: I've been using [this userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Preview-Antifocus) for ages for this

Comment: This was reported and fixed a while ago https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295666 but got broken again for some reason