# Disable annoying autofocus when clicking preview

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, edits, editor

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Start writing a long answer.
2. Scroll to the end of the preview.
3. Click it.

**Current behavior**

The textarea is focused magically.

This is so annoying:

- You can't select text in the preview
- You can't copy text from the preview
- When you click "Show code snippet" to show a hidden code snippet, it disappears from view
- When you click "Run code snippet" to run a code snippet, it disappears from view

> [image]

**Desired behavior**

There should be no autofocus.

Just remove this event listener from `cdn.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.en.js`

```js
o.find(".wmd-preview").click(function(e){
    2!=e.which&&$(this).siblings().find("textarea").focus()
})
```

**Workaround**

Meanwhile, I use this userscript:

```js
var click = $.fn.click;
$.fn.click = function() {
  click.apply(this.not(document.getElementById('wmd-preview')), arguments);
  return this;
};
```

Comment: Have experienced this so many times that I thought it was a [feature](http://forums.imore.com/attachments/jailbreaking-unlocking-hacks-themes-mods/27349d1361657121t-hiding-icons-using-sbsettings-bug-its_not_a_bug_its_a_feature_card-p137081274885571207envwi_400.jpg)!

Comment: By the way, I'm not the only person annoyed by this. See [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292348/#comment187826_292348)

Comment: @BhargavRao They probably thought it was a feature. But they should have asked in [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) before implementing it.

Comment: [The Old New Thing: When designing your user interface, be mindful of the selection-readers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/28/10617693.aspx) well, it's even worse

Comment: How did you create that animated gif / screenshot-in-motion?  That's very cool for bug reporting.

Comment: @kevinarpe I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), a lightweight GPL free software.

Comment: The reason for this autofocus is to remind you that **you can't edit the preview**.  So many times I've tried to do that by selecting a portion of the preview and started typing away.  The real solution of course is a real WYSIWYG editor, obviating the need for a preview at all.  And we need cold fusion.

Comment: I disagree with your black-and-white statement: `There should be no autofocus`. I agree this is annoying, but I've found it useful in the past. I think there should be an option to disable (or enable) autofocus on the answer page.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I disagree. Normal text in webpages can't be edited (except if `contentEditable`), so I'm surprised you attempted to do it. And  I hate WYSIWYG editors because they don't do what I want; WYSIWYW would be better.

Comment: @That1Guy That would be great. But if it's too difficult to implement, I prefer getting rid of the autofocus.

Comment: Agreed @Oriol this autofocus is a crude, oppressive feature.  But something needs to take its place.  I'd prefer a fading red border or background on the preview, with "edit the markdown, not the preview" discreetly somewhere.  But the conditions would be tricky.  Not on merely click, but **select + keystroke** (though not Ctrl-C).  Also on a slow **second click**, as if frustratedly trying to insert a cursor for typing.  A fast double-click could do the autofocus lurch.

Comment: It just needs a light diagonal line pattern "watermark" or something through the back of the preview that indicates it isn't the textarea in a subtle but obvious way.

Comment: There's an extension for Firefox called "Right to Click" that lets you disable certain javascript annoyances. You can disable them on demand or permanantly for a specific page.  (I use it on sites that grab the up and down arrow for other uses).

Comment: @Oriol In an attempt to avoid seeming presumptuous, I'll avoid using words like "probably" or "likely" but I can't imagine it would be terribly difficult to implement something along the lines of `if(focusEnabled){autofocus()};` As another alternative, perhaps a double-click event could trigger autofocus instead of relying on an option.

Comment: @That1Guy Yes, but they should also implement some kind of checkbox to enable/disable it, decide where they place it, store the preference in the server... And maybe they prefer investing their time in other things. In that case, removing the event listener is simpler.

Comment: @Oriol That's very true. Hopefully they'll elect to invest the time to offer us an option. I often find the "feature" annoying, but at the same time I'd hate to lose the convenience of facilitating the editing a minor typo or grammatical error with a simple click of the mouse.

Comment: Curiously, this behavior doesn't happen in the first place when you use the in-place editing feature. (Steps to reproduce: click "edit" above, then click the preview.) I don't recall seeing any bug reports about *that*, so it looks like nobody's really missed it. ;-)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Interesting, I'm sure previously it happened with in-place editing too. Well, at least now it's half fixed.

Comment: some background on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30095/clicking-on-the-preview-box-when-trying-to-click-on-the-edit-box

Comment: This bug seems to be appearing again.

Comment: I don't think it ever went away.

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424076/12715723

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just changed it so that:

- Just clicking in the preview will focus the editor, as before
- Selecting text in the preview will do nothing, so you can copy it

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** Completed the whole thing, now the editor isn't focused either when clicking *Show code snippet*, *Hide code snippet*, *Run code snippet* or *Hide results*.

Comment: That's better, but clicking "show/hide/run code snippet" shouldn't focus the editor neither.

Comment: @Oriol Aaand done!

Comment: Snippet buttons have this problem again :(

Answer (score 9):

There's actually a work-around for selecting and copying text from the preview: the click handler doesn't fire until you *release* the mouse button, so you can select the text you want and, *while holding down the mouse button*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.

That said, I agree that this "feature" can be extremely annoying.  It's also inconsistent: apparently, it doesn't happen (for some reason) when editing existing questions or answers in-line.  That's probably a bug, but I haven't seen any complaints about it, so I guess people don't really mind the absence of this focus-transfer very much.  Thus, I'd personally prefer to see the whole feature disabled.

In fact, I've just added code to do this (based on Oriol's code above) to the development branch of my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  If no surprising side effects turn up, this code will be part of the next stable SOUP release (v1.32); in the mean time, those interested in testing the feature may [install the development version](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) directly.

My version of Oriol's code is slightly modified to be more robust against loading order issues, and also adds a replacement *double*-click handler to give people who *like* the ability to return to the edit box by clicking the preview a way to still do so, just by clicking twice:

```js
// remove any existing click handlers
$( '.wmd-preview' ).off( 'click' );

// block installation of further click handlers
var oldClick = $.fn.click;
$.fn.click = function () {
    var that = ( arguments.length > 0 ? this.not( $('.wmd-preview') ) : this );
    oldClick.apply( that, arguments );
    return this;
};

// add replacement double-click handler
$( document ).on( 'dblclick', '.wmd-preview', function () {
    $( 'textarea', this.parentNode ).focus();
} );
```

(Ideally, I think that double-clicking on the preview should move the focus to the edit box *at the point in the text that you clicked*.  I have an idea on how to perhaps do that — it involves selection ranges and some fuzzy text matching — but that still needs more development and testing work.  Anyway, for now, double-clicking just works the same way as single-clicking would without this fix.)

Comment: Your code has a bug. `$(document).not('.wmd-preview').length` is `0`. In order to make it work properly, in `not()` you must use a real DOM object, not a string. Otherwise, try opening the inbox and then click somewhere to close it: it won't close, because `document` has been filtered out.

Comment: Huh, that's a pretty strange result. Looks like `this.not( $('.wmd-preview') )` works as intended, though. Will fix.

Answer (score 2):

This was tested and appears to have been resolved a while back. I've updated the status to completed.

Comment: This does not appear to have been fixed. I can still trivially reproduce it on this page, and on Stack Overflow, and [others encounter it too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424076).