# Improvement request for Stack Snippets when misclicking preview area

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, stack-snippets

While I was answering a question from Stack Overflow, I put some code in the *Stack Snippets* area. Sometimes, when I want to change back the code that I have typed, I wrongly click on the sentence `edit the above snippet`, causing the page to scroll up. This will have a bad impact if you use a smartphone browser or when you have typed a long answer but scroll up too far. I hope this fix is workable so it will be of great help to the answerers on Stack Overflow. What do you think?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295666/ - it was marked as status-completed, but has never actually been fixed. It occurs with any post, not just with Stack Snippets.

Comment: Maybe it have been edited in prod, but after they made another update it have been revert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=09d93d5de0f4 :

```javascript
s.find(".js-wmd-preview").click((function(t) {
    if ("show-hide" !== t.target.className && !t.target.localName.startsWith("input")) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var n = window.getSelection();
            if (n.anchorNode !== n.focusNode || n.anchorOffset !== n.focusOffset) return
        }
        t.which != e.S.MIDDLE_MOUSE && $(this).siblings().find("textarea").focus()
    }
}))
```

This matches the behaviour described in [Konamiman's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323319/5223757), so it looks like the behaviour hasn't changed since then. There isn't an easy way to adapt this code to fix *this* problem. Consider the Stack Snippet:

```html
Hi, I'm HTML!
```

The HTML for its Stack Snippet preview looks like this.

```html
<p>
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-code" style="display: block;">
      <pre class="lang-html snippet-code-html s-code-block">
<code class="hljs language-xml">Hi, I'm HTML!</code></pre>
      <div class="snippet-result">
        <div class="snippet-ctas">
          <button type="button" class="s-btn s-btn__primary">
            <span class="icon-play-white _hover"></span>
            <span> Run code snippet</span>
          </button>
          <input class="copySnippet s-btn s-btn__filled" type="button" value="Copy snippet to answer" style="display: none;">
          <button type="button" class="s-btn hideResults" style="display: none;">Hide results</button>
          <div class="popout-code">
            <a class="snippet-expand-link">Expand snippet</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-result-code" style="display: none;">
          <iframe name="sif194" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit snippet-box-result" tc-textcontent="true" data-tc-id="w-0.3645120798882838" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<p>
  <sup>
    <a href="#" class="edit-snippet" data-id="0">edit the above snippet</a>
  </sup>
</p>
```

The "edit the above snippet" paragraph is separate from the Stack Snippet proper. It's hard to distinguish it from any other paragraph (without adding a class to it) – and even if you could, that would only fix horizontal misclicks. Perhaps there's [something in jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) that can solve this problem.

---

Similar issues:

- Running a Stack Snippet jumps to the editor.
- Clicking "hide results" jumps to the editor.
- Clicking on a link in your answer jumps to the editor.
- Copy Snippet to Answer appears if you click "Expand snippet" then "Return to post".

Comment: Very insightful for knowing HTML and Javascript implementation of Stack Snippets!

Comment: An easy way to fix it would be to simply remove that whole `.click` handler. It makes no sense.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd be in favour of that, but some people like the feature: it reminds them not to try to type in the preview. If the WYSIWYG editor used in Stack Overflow for Teams had a Markdown preview, people who rely on the click handler could use the WYSIWYG editor and we could safely remove it – but people like _me_ need Markdown and rely on the preview, so I wouldn't be happy with switching to the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 99% of text on webpages is not in a WYSIWYG editor. If someone needs an additional reminder that the preview text is not such an editor, they'll see when they notice that no text cursor appears, or when they try to type and nothing happens. I would rather those (rare, unobservant) users get *very* slightly inconvenienced than for something that damages the UI for almost all other users.