# Remove the listener on clicking the preview or make it focus in the same position

Tags: feature-request, user-experience

When composing or editing a post, if you click the preview, the text area becomes focused.

Here are two main problems:

1. I scrolled the preview to the end, accidentally clicked it and... ARGH! The page scrolled to the top.
2. I clicked the preview, accidentally typed something... Oh, no! The random characters are now in the post.

Please remove the listener or at least make the cursor in the text area move to the same place, where the preview was clicked (to get at least *any* benefit of the listener).

---

P.S. I've seen [Disable annoying autofocus when clicking preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295666) with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but the listener wasn't removed. Also, my proposition is slightly different.

Comment: And even more: the issue occurres even when you click a button in a runned code snippet.

Comment: I have also encountered this and find it obnoxious. It very definitely has not been fixed, contra the resolution of that other question. Curiously, it doesn't happen when editing, only when submitting a new post.

Comment: Point 2 isn't very strong. Where _else_ would you expect your typed characters to appear?

Comment: "_or at least make the cursor in the text area move to the same place_" I think that would be a nice _double-click_ feature. IIRC, VS Code's builtin markdown preview works like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus I typed some characters *accidentally*, so, without the listener, they wouldn't appear *anywhere*.

Comment: @Cerbrus if I click the preview, I would expect the text area to *lose focus*, and therefore would be surprised by typed characters appearing there. I would expect them not to appear anywhere, because I would not expect any UI element to have focus that could accept the text.